# TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the following error every time i try to update a table on one server from data on another server **"TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available".** Here is the update statement:

```
update a
  set a.vendorID = b.SubID
  from ana.[FleetPlus].[dbo].[ServiceHistory] as a inner join ppcor.[subcontractors].[dbo].[Subcontractors] as b
  on a.vendorID = b.FleetID
```

this update query hangs for about 5-10 mins and then gives me that error message. I can run a select statement on this, so i am confused. i thought it was a problem with my linked servers and i checked the SSCM and the Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled on both servers. This is only updating around 10k records so its not too many. any suggestions on what is going on or what else i need to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with linked server.
Do not know which one, but run these two selects and see where you have that error:

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ana.[FleetPlus].[dbo].[ServiceHistory];
GO
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ppcor.[subcontractors].[dbo].[Subcontractors];
GO
```

Then you'd have to troubleshoot that linked server.

**BTW** That is extremely bad practice to link tables from different servers. That means you have to do a Full table scan on remote server, copy these data over the network, allocate memory on your SQL Server for these data and only then do a SELECT.

Comment: I will try this. Do you recommend if I do need to link two tables from two different servers I make a copy of one of the tables and put it in the dB that the other table is in? What is the recommended best practice to solve this issue if you do need to link two tables from different servers? @Slava Murygin

Comment: That is very broad question. Not sure if there is a simple answer. If your query is supporting some kind of reporting, the good practice would be to use an ETL process to collect all data together in one place (data mart) or prepare reports for publishing.